# If else statement problems

Tags: java

why wont it let me use the if else statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
   String pack;
   int hours;

   System.out.print("Please enter Package code:  ");
   pack = keyboard.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Please enter Package code:  ");
   pack = keyboard.nextLine();

   **if pack = "a";**
```

im getting error under if
Im not sure if what the problem is.

Comment: Does that look like an `if-else` block?

Comment: What is the **exact** error?

Comment: i figured it out thanks though!

Comment: Welcome @Robbie I think this is your first question ever to stackoverflow.

Comment: it was lol but thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
if (pack.equals("a")){
     //do something here
}
```

should be the syntax of an if statement comparing 2 strings

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper syntax. Also, when comparing strings you should use `equals`

To fix the issue, change `if pack = "a";` to

```
if (pack.equals("a")) {
    // do stuff
}
```